# arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: command not found

Tags: linux

I am trying to compile C++ code for ARM architecture. I don't know exactly the full name of processor (waiting for information from some hardware guy), I know only it is some ARM.
The problem which I have.
I use command in order to compile my resource files for ARM architecture:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ myApp.cpp -g -Wall -o myApp
```

and also

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc myApp.cpp -g -Wall -lstdc++ -o myApp
```

and gets output:

```
-bash: arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: command not found
```

and

```
-bash: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
```

In linux which I used I am not sure if there is installed gcc,g++ arm package...
There is:

```
locate arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
locate arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
locate arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

, there is none:

```
locate arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
locate arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

I am not allowed to do some tries and install arm package, because this linux is running on some server to which many developers are attached.
setting PATH in shell:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/eds/x86_64/13.1-2/embedded/ds-5/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

or with gcc
doesn't solve the issue.
Setting it in:

```
~/.bashrc
```

also doesn't solve the issue because additional problems occurs, I cannot connect to linux server.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If the toolchain is not installed and you are not permitted to install it then what exactly are you asking help for?

Answer (score 8):

for kernel or uboot cross compiling below commands are enough:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt-get install -y libncurses-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libqt4-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get install -y u-boot-tools
sudo apt-get install -y device-tree-compiler
```

but for c++ cross compiling you should install g++ using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```